# Load wordpress posts into Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to call a list of my `Wordpress` posts and save them to a Javascript array of objects (JSON, really). I want something like:

```
var articles = [
  {
  title: 'Title 1',
  author: 'Author 1',
  byline: 'Byline 1'
  },{
  title: 'Title 2',
  author: 'Author 2',
  byline: 'Byline 2'
  }
]
```

I'm new to PHP so don't quite understand how looping in and out of the `<?php ?>` tags works, nor how variables and functions work in this sense. I'm trying the following:

```
<script>
    var articles = [];
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1); 
        $posts= get_posts( $args );
        if ($posts) {
            foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?> // exit PHP
                var obj = {}; // Create a JS object
                obj.title = <?php the_title(); ?>; // Append the title to the object
                obj.byline = <?php the_excerpt(); ?>; // Append the byline
                articles.push(obj); // Push object into the array
            <?php }
        }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: See if this helps http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: @elclanrs That looks cool, although it seems like you can only get a maximum of 10 posts returned using this API and I need all of them... (the documentation seems to be non-existent though, please point me in the right direction if wrong)

Comment: The documentation looks good http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Comment: @elclanrs Ah, didn't see it. For anyone who stumbles across this, the correct way to do it is: `'/api/get_posts/?count=-1'`